# What do we say to a person having an illness?

Tags: phrase-request, phrase-choice

Some conditions have different response.
For example when someone dies we say condiliansa, when we welcome someone
we say bene venuti,
But when someone get a disease what do we say to him?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When someone dies we say "condoglianze" that means "I am suffering with you."
When we welcome someone we say "benvenuti".
When someone get a disease we say "auguri di pronta guarigione" or more simply "tanti auguri".

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Answer (score 2):

I would not say "tanti auguri" to someone who is ill! That sounds weird.

I would say: **"Guarisci presto!"** or **"Rimettiti presto!"** (2nd person singular, that is, for people you address with "tu") / **"Guarisca presto"** or **"Si rimetta presto"** (3rd person singular, that is, for people you address with "lei"/"signora"/"signore).

*Rimettersi* means "get better".

If you need to be very formal, like if you are writing a card to bring to someone who is in hospital or very ill, you can write: **"Auguri di pronta guarigione"**. This is ok for people you address with "tu" and "lei".